# Apply jQuery-UI sortable() to accordion() element only when collapsed

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, accordion, jquery-ui-sortable

Is it possible to make a jquery accordion sortable only when all elements are collapsed? I have a sortable accordion, but when the active element is moved , it breaks the css on the page (rearranges the columns,). I know this is likely a problem with the css on the site rather than the accordion, but I don't have permissions to adjust all of the css. Below is the code I am using to create the accordion:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>

    var selected = new  Array();
    var ids = new Array();
    var counter = <?php echo (req('fd_id'))? count($results): 0;?>;
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#livesearch").bind("keyup", function () {
                var value = escape($("#livesearch").val());
                if (value.length == 0)
                    $("#results").fadeOut(500);
                else
                {
                    $("#results").fadeIn(500);
                    $("#results").load("<?php echo matry::base_to('utilities/search/referral_search&str=')?>" + value);
                }
            });
        $(function () {
            $("#trip_list").accordion({
                header: ">li >h3",
                collapsible: true
            }).sortable({
                axis: 'y',
                handle: 'h3',
                stop: function(event, ui)
                {
                    ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
                }
            });

            });
        $("#livesearch").blur(function(){$("#livesearch").val(""); $("#results").fadeOut(500);});
        $("#reset").click(function(){$("#trip_list").html("");});
        $("button.remove").on('click', function (){
                $(this).parents('li').remove();
            });
        $("button#save").on('click', function (){
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '<?php echo matry::base_to('utilities/crm/field_day_save');?>',
                    data: $("form#trip_form").serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data)
                    {
                        $("#alerts").html(data.alert);
                        $("#form_id").val(data.id);
                    }
                    });
            });
    });

    function selectItem(id)
    {
        if (counter < 20) //only allow 20 referral sources at a time
        {
            $.get("<?php echo matry::base_to('utilities/field_day'); ?>&rfcode=" + id + "&count=" + counter, function(data){
                        $("#trip_list").append(data).accordion('destroy').accordion({header: "li >h3", collapsible: true});}); 
            counter++;
        }
    }

</script>
```

**Update**

I have added the following, but it only works on the Second or more panels. The first panel ignores it. Any suggestions?

```
$(function () {
            $("#trip_list").accordion({
                header: "li >h3",
                active: false,
                collapsible: true,
                activate: function(){if($(this).accordion('option', 'active')){$(this).sortable('disable');}else $(this).sortable('enable');}
            }).sortable({
                axis: 'y',
                handle: 'h3',
                stop: function(event, ui)
                {
                    ui.item.children( "h3" ).triggerHandler( "focusout" );
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1. Use sortable() methods in accordion() event**

Using the accordion's [`accordionactivate`](http://api.jqueryui.com/accordion/#event-activate) event which fires whenever an accordion panel is opened or closed, you can check if the accordion is collapsed or not, and apply the [`.sortable('enable')`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-enable) or [`.sortable('disable')`](http://api.jqueryui.com/sortable/#method-disable) methods in accordance.

**2. Detect if the accordion is collapsed**

To detect the state of the accordion in the event handler, you can check the `ui.newPanel` property, which is a jQuery object containing the newly opened accordion panel. If `ui.newPanel` is not an empty object, then it means the accordion is not collapsed (i.e a closed panel was clicked). Similarly, if `ui.newPanel` is an empty object, then it means the accordion is completely collapsed (i.e an open panel was clicked and no new panel opened in its place).

**Example and demo**

```
$('#accordion').accordion({...}).sortable({...});

$('#accordion').on('accordionactivate', function (event, ui) {
     // Accordion is not collapsed
    if (ui.newPanel.length) {
        $('#accordion').sortable('disable');
     // Accordion is collapsed
    } else {
        $('#accordion').sortable('enable');
    }
});
```

See **[jsFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Vaybz/)**

Comment: Thanks, the suggestion works on the panel 2+, but not on the first, do you know how to apply activate to the first panel also?

Comment: @Mike Updated my answer with detection method.

Comment: @Mike Added a sample snippet and jsFiddle example. Sorry it took so long. jsFiddle has been very unresponsive lately.